# How do you inject a return value from a method

Tags: c#, dependency-injection

I've created a class to handle information returned from a method but it's not being injected; I'm getting the following exception.
[image]

Program.cs

```
builder.Services.AddSingleton<IBusinessResult, BusinessResult>();
```

BusinessResult.cs

```
public class BusinessResult : IBusinessResult
{
    public bool Success { get; set; } = false;
    public object? Result { get; set; } = null;
    public Exception? Exception { get; set; } = null;
}
```

Usage

```
    private readonly ILogger _logger;
    private readonly DbEntities _db;
    private IBusinessResult _businessResult;

    public UserBusiness(ILogger logger, DbEntities db)
    {
        _logger = logger;
        _db = db;
    }

    private IBusinessResult Validate(User model, ValidationType validationType)
    {
        try
        {
            //put required validation code here
            _businessResult.Success = true;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            _businessResult.Exception = ex;
            _logger.LogError($"UserBusiness.Validate - ValidationType: {validationType.ToString()}\r\nModel: {JsonSerializer.Serialize<User>(model)}");
            throw;
        }

        return _businessResult;
    }
```

Comment: `_businessResult` is a private field that doesn't appear to be assigned anywhere. Dependency injection isn't going to fill private members. As you are supposed to return the value, you are presumably also expected to create the instance. If not, you'd have to add an `IBusinessResult` to your constructor so it does get picked up by DI. In this case there appears to be no need to encapsulate `IBusinessResult` with an interface in any case, as it's just a simple data holder. You might as well use a concrete `record`.

Answer (score 0):

Dependency Injection is (most commonly) set up by requesting the dependencies in the constructor, and assigning the private fields.  You've registered your service correctly, just add it to the constructor:

```
public UserBusiness(ILogger logger, DbEntities db, IBusinessResult businessResult)
{
    _logger = logger;
    _db = db;
    _businessResult = businessResult;
}
```

As an aside, this class looks odd to be a singleton or injected at all, but that's a different question.